# tcpdump packets are captured before fragmentation

Tags: tcpdump, fragmentation

I have a setup as below.

```
[ Host A ]  <-> [Rtr-A] <-> [Rtr-M] <-> [Rtr-B] <-> [ Host B]
```

I have set MTU of out interface of Rtr-A interface ( towards 'Rtr-M' ) to 600
I am capturing packets from 'Host A' and 'Rtr-A'.
I have sent a data of size 1000 from 'Host A' to 'Host B'.
While looking at the packets captured, I can see that ICMP packet with fragmentation required came from Rtr-A to 'Host A' and after that packet from Host A is still 1000 bytes where as the packet reached in Rtr-A is smaller chunks. Which means I assume that after packet is captured from 'Host A', it is fragmented.

Is this expected behaviour ?. Is there any way I can capture fragmented packet from 'Host A' itself.

~S

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal and expected behavior when you capture locally.  If you want to see the packets as they appear on the wire, then you'll need to capture externally using a TAP, the SPAN port of a switch or a hub if you can find one.

A good article I recommend reading is Jasper Bongertz's ["The drawbacks of local packet captures"](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2014/05/the-drawbacks-of-local-packet-captures/), where this very issue is mentioned in *"Sideeffect #2 -Woah, BIG packets! And small ones, too!"*.  You might also want to refer to the Wireshark [Ethernet capture setup](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/CaptureSetup/Ethernet) wiki page.